# Unable to write to plist file

Tags: ios, plist, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary, writetofile

I've found several questions here on the site with people who have a similar problem, but I'm still not able to resolve mine. Here's the thing:

I'm making an iOS app that contains two plist files. When the user opens the app for the first time, the application takes care of moving these two files to the Documents directory. I know this code works, since I'm subsequently able to read from each of the files in the Documents directory path. However, I'm not able to write to any of them for apparent unknown reasons. Here is the code I use to write to the first plist file:

```
+ (void)insertNewElementWith:(NSArray *)objects andKeys:(NSArray *)keys {
    NSString *filePath = [self returnPathForFirstPlistFile];
    NSMutableDictionary *contentOfFirstPlistFile = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
    [contentOfFirstPlistFile setObject:dictionary forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[contentOfFirstPlistFile count]]];
    [contentOfFirstPlistFile writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    [dictionary release];
}
```

`returnPathForFirstPlistFile` **does** work, since `contentOfFirstPlistFile` contains `{ }` rather than `null`. Can anyone explain to me, though, why it keeps returning `{ }`, even though the above method has been called several times.

**Update**

Here is the code I use to place the files in the Documents directory. `placePlistsInDocumentsDirectory` is **only** called when the user logs in through the app, so this only happens once.

```
+ (NSString *)returnPathForFirstPlistFile {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"First.plist"];

    return filePath;
}

+ (NSString *)returnPathForSecondPlistFile {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSLog(@"%@", [paths objectAtIndex:0]);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Second.plist"];

    return filePath;
}

+ (void)placePlistsInDocumentsDirectory {
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *firstPlistPath = [self returnPathForFirstPlistFile];
    NSString *secondPlistPath = [self returnPathForSecondPlistFile];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:firstPlistPath]) {
        NSError *error;
        NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"First" ofType:@"plist"];
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath:firstPlistPath error:&error];
    }

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:secondPlistPath]) {
        NSError *error;
        NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Second" ofType:@"plist"];
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath:secondPlistPath error:&error];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:[contentOfFirstPlistFile count]]
```

Gives you an NSNumber object. This is not a valid key for a dictionary, the key has to be an NSString. Use

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[contentOfFirstPlistFile count]]
```

Instead. Though, if you are using numbers as keys in a dictionary, why not use an array?

I have attempted to reproduce this issue myself and the only way I could manage it was to use a plist that did not have a dictionary as its root object. This returned a dictionary that was not nil, but did not allow any modifications. This could not then be written back to the file. Looking at some of your earlier questions, you were using an array based plist before, so this may be the issue.

Comment: Thanks, but still not working. When applying a BOOL variable to the `writeToFile` line, it returns negative even though I've replaced the NSNumber with the NSString. I've tried with an array as well, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: What do you see if you log `contentOfFirstPlistFile` before and after you add the `dictionary` to it?

Comment: An empty dictionary before and a dictionary with content after.

Comment: OK, and are you sure that you're not copying over that file again with your "opening app for the first time" code? If in that method, you create a new dictionary by reading the path, what does it contain?